# document doesn't fully load, cuts off after one subsection

Tags: sectioning, pdf, chapters

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
 
\newgeometry{
    top=0.75in,
    bottom=0.75in,
    outer=0.95in,
    inner=0.95in
}
  
\title{{\bf \Huge Corporate Finance and Controlling}\newline
{\Large uni}

\vspace{10mm}

{\bf \Huge Fundamental Analysis}

\vspace{2mm}

\author{{\bf \Large name}\\
\vspace{5mm}
{\bf \large Guide: Prof}}

\vspace{10mm}

\date {\today}

\begin{figure*}[!b]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{uniLogo.jpg}
\end{figure*}
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter*{Introduction}
some text here

\begin{figure*}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{operatingMargin.png}
    \caption{Operating Margin of the selected four companies, 2017-2022.}
\end{figure*}

some more text here 

\let\clearpage\relax


\chapter{Financial Metrics}

some text here


\section{Operating Margin}

some text here

\vspace{0.2in}
Operating margin can be calculated using the following formula:

\[
    \text{Operating Margin} = \frac{\text{Operating income(revenue-operting expenses)}}{\text{Revenue}}*100
\]

or it can also be written as:

\[
    \text{Operating Margin} = \frac{\text{EBIT\footnotemark}}{\text{Revenue}}
\]

\footnotetext{EBIT = Earnings Before Interest and Taxes}

some text here 

some text here

\section{Price-to-Earnings ratio}

Price-to-earnings ratio or P/E ratio is used to measure the valuation of a company's stock. 

It is calculated using the following formula:
\[
    \text{P/E Ratio} = \frac{\text{Price Per Share}}{\text{EPS\footnotemark}}
\]

\footnotetext{EPS = Earnings Per Share}


some text here 


\section{Price-to-Book Ratio}

Price-to-Book ratio or P/B ratio is a comparison between firm's market capitalization to its book value, investors mostly use this ratio to locate undervalued companies.

It is calculated using the following formula:
\[
    \text{P/B Ratio} = \frac{\text{Price Per Share}}{\text{Book Value per Share}}
\]

some text here



\end{document}
'''
```

After the section operating margin, nothing more is visible in the pdf, it just abruptly cuts off. even in the contents page nothing after the operating margin section loads.

Comment: do not do \let\clearpage\relax. You are breaking latex with this.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Brilliant. Thank you very much. How else can I start a new chapter in the same page as the end of the previous chapter?

Comment: use `article` not report and `\section` not `\chapter`